# PyCharm not using my configured virtualenv interpreter

Tags: pycharm

I've added my virtualenv on the settings and selected it to be the default interpreter like so:

[image]

Now when I try to run a script, I notice that it's actually not using the virtualenv's interpreter:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I've tried restarting, I've tried selecting another interpreter and re-selecting. And so far no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your script configurations.

[image: edit configurations]

Is your script using a different python interpreter?

[image: python interpreter setting]

Comment: Ah that was the problem. Would setting the default interpreter not automatically change this? That's strange.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat Changing the default will not change the currently selected interpreter for any project. That is actually made to be that way so as to not mess up interpreters already set for other projects. Changing the default will only change for any new project that is created

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks